# How to pass "this" in a JSON string which then needs to be converted to an JS Obj

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a small JS method where I attach `data-*` attrs to a link, bind a event to the link and send the `data-*` values to a 3rd party JS analytics API.

```
<a href="#" class="js-analytics-proxy" data-trackme='{"obj": this, "rmethod": "track", "partial-path": "/foo/bar" }'
```

And in a JS file

```
$('js-analytics-proxy').live('click', function() { 
    3rdParty.webTrack('site1', 'foo', $(this).data('trackme'));
});
```

The problem is:

1. By default, `$(this).data('trackme')` will return a `String`
2. If I `$.parseJSON(..)` it, it will fail because `"obj": this` is not a valid key/val pair in JSON string notation.
3. No matter what, when passed "thought" the `data-*` attr, only the String representation of of the JS obj name is passed.

I do realize that `data-*` are for "data" and arguable `this` is not data, but code, so it doesn't belong in it to begin with. Also, I would like to avoid "hardcoding" the obj: this key/val pair into my JS class (basically taking it out of the data-* attr, and adding it to the args in the JS method if possible.

---

Update 1: I am using this because the 3rdParty JS library expects it. The current implementation has

```
onclick='3rdParty.webTrack("site1", "foo", {"obj": this, "rmethod": "track", "partial-path": "/foo/bar" }'
```

*all* over the markup. We are looking at a less obtrusive approach. Sometimes there are other key/val pairs which pass other JS objects in as well. The obj: this was an isolated example to illustrate the problem

---

Update 2: This seems dangerous, but I could create a convention where properties prefixed with "js:" will have their string value eval'd. `{ "js:obj": "this" }` would be transformed to `{ "obj": this ...` of course this comes with all the dangers of using eval, which is something I would like to avoid at all cost.

I could also simply change any String value of "this" to the current scope `this` which would be less dangerous, but IMO not very elegant.

Comment: What are you using the `this` for? When the link gets clicked, you can refer to the element as simply `this` :)

Comment: you are absolutely right when you say ```this``` is code, not data. 
i cannot image what "this" would mean. 
would in depend on _where_ the json is parsed? i.e. ```this``` would refer to some callback inside the parser. please state your intention, why would you want to use ```this```? it seems absolutely pointless

Comment: See my update - the 3rdParty code does things with it. I haven't delved into that code, but I assume it expects the DOM element so it can pull attrs off it.

Comment: Even if there are other live JS objects, you can refer them in the same way as `data.obj = this` was done...

Comment: @Esailija i think i lost you. my initial goal was to allow for all the data to be managed in the Markup (which represents data). The problem is the commercial 3rd party API (sometimes) uses JS Objs at "data" (I dont have control of that code), which is where this starts to fall apart. If I could figure out what exactly is being retrieved from `obj` (for isntance href and text) I could create my own JS obj and pass it in as a string obj: { "href", "/foo.html", "text": "the name of the link" } .. but I dont have access to the code and it might be hard to figure out.

Comment: @Esailija haha - that should read: "I think you lost ME" :)

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.data()` can store objects](http://jsfiddle.net/WrAzw/). Assign them using `data()` so jQuery can store them as objects. Also, retrieve them using `data()` as well.

```
//assign them via data()
$(element).data('trackme',{
    data : 'foo'
    ...
});

//retrieve them using data()
$(element).data('trackme');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `"obj": this`, it's not json and won't work.

After that, it will become legit json and the following will work, given that `ThirdParty.webTrack` actually expects a DOM element:

```
$('js-analytics-proxy').live('click', function() {
    var data = $.parseJSON( $(this).data( "trackme" ) );
    data.obj = this;
    ThirdParty.webTrack('site1', 'foo', data);
});
```

Comment: Right, the problem is data.obj is not always a param. I wanted to allow the data passed to be controlled in a centralized location (the data-* attrs). I may have to figure out all the cases where a obj is expected though and put a hack in like this. My other option would be to check properties and assume a String property of "this" should be replaced with the JS obj `this`.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind the click to the event, you can grab the reference to `this` and add it to the object that you are trying to pass, maybe using something like this:

```
$('js-analytics-proxy').live('click', function() { 
    3rdParty.webTrack('site1', 'foo', $.extend(
        $.parseJSON($(this).data('trackme')), 
        { 'obj' : this }
    );
});
```

Obviously, you would also remove the `"obj": this` part from the `data-trackme` attribute of the `a` element.

Comment: Right, i mentioned that i wanted to avoid this in my original post. Depending on the link the JSON obj passed to webTrack(..) can be different (not all have 'obj', etc.)

Comment: @empire29 I see now, I misunderstood that paragraph before. You mentioned that they don't all have an `obj` key. Is there a pattern that you can spot? Or, at least, if there is an `obj` key, is its value always `this`? Although it is more work, I think you're better off finding a way to extract the "code" parts that are passed to the 3rd party and attach them to the objects on click rather than squeeze them in as data attributes to the DOM elements. This is, I imagine, the reason that the jQuery `.data()` method does not store the data in the DOM elements themselves, but rather in `$.cache`.